# PHP convert associative array into indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

So long story short, I have the array  $total which looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] =>  Array
            (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            ) 
    [1] => Array 
            (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 7 
            [2] => 8
            ) 
    [2] => Array 
            ( 
            [0] => 9 
            [1] => 10 
            ) 
    )
```

However I need to pass it to a function that looks like this:

```
$count = cartesian(
Array("GH20"),
Array(1,3),
Array(6,7,8), 
Array(9,10)
);
```

I have asked a similar question but I suspect the answer they gave was correct, I do not think asked the question in the right way. The cartesain function does not seem to accept:

```
$count = cartesian(
Array($total[0]),
Array($total[1]),
Array($total[2])
);
```

After some digging around I believe this is down to the fact that the arrays have keys which is not causing an error however instead of any values being returned, it just returns "array" for everything.

My question, in two parts then, is how do I remove the keys from the arrays so it is formatted as required. If possible, could the be done dynamically?

I have tried what everybody suggestes on google which is use the array_values() function, but this did not help

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks, Nick

As requested, casertain function:

```
function cartesian() {
$_ = func_get_args();
if(count($_) == 0)
    return array(array());
$a = array_shift($_);
$c = call_user_func_array(__FUNCTION__, $_);
$r = array();
foreach($a as $v)
    foreach($c as $p)
        $r[] = array_merge(array($v), $p);
return $r;
}
```

This is my desired output (Every permutation of ($total):

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
    [0] => GH20
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 9
)
    [1] => Array (
    [0] => GH20
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 10
)
    [2] => Array (
    [0] => GH20
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 9
)
    [3] => Array (
    [0] => GH20
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 10
)
    [4] => Array (
    [0] => GH20
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 9
)
    [5] => Array (
    [0] => GH20
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 10
)
    [6] => Array (
    [0] => GH20
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 9
)
    [7] => Array (
    [0] => GH20
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 10
)
    [8] => Array (
    [0] => GH20
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 9
)
    [9] => Array (
    [0] => GH20
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 10
)
    [10] => Array (
    [0] => GH20
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 9
)
    [11] => Array (
    [0] => GH20
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 10
)
)
```

Comment: `$count = cartesian($total[0], $total[1], $total[2])`. It wants single dimensional arrays, your "*cartesain function does not seem to accept*" code is passing array-wrapped-arrays, which makes them multidimensional again.

Comment: `cartesian(Array("GH20"), $total[0], $total[1], $total[2]);`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Any suggestions on how I might dynamically pass the contents of an array to the cartesain function?

Comment: @sectus This did not work, as suspected Mike was right.

Comment: @NicholasMordecai, show your cartesain function

Comment: @NicholasMordecai this would be trying to swimming upstream. What you want to do instead is have a (possibly separate) `cartesian` function that knows how to deal with two dimensional arrays instead.

Comment: @NicholasMordecai 2 questions :D: 1. you want to convert the array in the first box to that in the second? 2. from where comes the string "GH20" ? (Also where is here in your question a function?)

Comment: Please, add example of input data and desired output data.

Comment: @sectus My input data is the array at the top of the page. The way it has to be formatted for my cartesain function to accept is the second block code down and the output data is simply a single array of every permutation of the input arrays. Nick

Comment: just put desired output to the question

Comment: @sectus Desired output is in the bottom. Thanks

Comment: This has been fixed by altering the cartesian function. Will mark your answer as being correct for the question. Many thanks, Kind regards, Nick!